# How to extract and return data from multiple tables via foreign keys with django rest?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following models:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    bar_id = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="bars")
    stock = models.IntegerField()
    
class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Note that one `Bar` can have multiple `Stock`

I would like, for one Bar, to retrieve and return all the stocks that are associated.

SO, in my urls, I have:

```
path('stock/<int:pk>/', views.StockListPerBar.as_view())
```

With the view being:

```
class StockListPerBar(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Bar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockListPerBarSerializer
```

And the serializer is:

```
class StockListPerBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ["name", "bars"]
```

This provide the following output:

```
{
    "name": "Some bar name",
    "bars": [
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
    ]
}
```

However, I would like the output to be a bit different, like so (truncated):

```
[
    {
        "id": 4,
        "stock": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "stock": 0
    }
]
```

How may I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create serializer for your `Stock` model and use it in related field

```py
class StockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ["id", "stock"]


class StockListPerBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bars = StockSerializer(many=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ["name", "bars"]
```

And you will have this output

```json
{
    "name": "Some bar name",
    "bars": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "stock": 10
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "stock": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Greetings you can simply add depth = 1 to your serializer files and you will get the result as wanted:

```
class StockListPerBarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
bars = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)

class Meta:
    model = Bar
    depth = 1
    fields = ["name", "bars"]
```

i think it should solve the issue